# Imgur API don't work anymore since few days

Tags: php, api, imgur

Since a few days the Imgur api don't work anymore on my site. I already renew my client id but nothing changed.

My code:

```html
    $client_id = '**';

        $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["imgupload"]["tmp_name"]);

        $url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json';
        $headers = array("Authorization: Client-ID $client_id");
        $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($file));

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
           CURLOPT_URL=> $url,
           CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
           CURLOPT_POST => 1,
           CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
           CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
           CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $pvars
        ));

        $json_returned = curl_exec($curl); // blank response
        $json_returned = json_decode($json_returned, true);
        $uploaded = $json_returned['data']['link'];
        //echo "Result: " . $uploaded ;

        curl_close ($curl);
```

Somebody know if something is changed in the api? The output of $json_returned is totally blankpage.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the [HTTP status](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) code being returned.

Comment: POST /3/image.json HTTP/1.1 Host: api.imgur.com Accept: */* Authorization: Client-ID ** Content-Length: 90724 Expect: 100-continue Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------ea77b3e878c97a31